# Jmeter Graph generator is throwing error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.ResponseTimesOverTimeGui

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

When I try to generate graphs using graph generator, I am getting below error and PNG files are not getting generated

```
2022-10-01 14:27:54,062 WARN o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Error encountered during shutdown of kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener@4652388c
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.ResponseTimesOverTimeGui
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:237) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:234) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:230) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.setPluginType(PluginsCMDWorker.java:73) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:137) ~[jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:507) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.ResponseTimesOverTimeGui
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:383) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:376) ~[?:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:227) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.2.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
2022-10-01 14:27:54,098 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/941Fy.png
```

Comment: Have followed this for setup https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/#:~:text=You%20have%202%20options%3A,is%20BEFORE%20Graphs%20Generator%20Listener and installed via plugin manager do I need to change any properties file or am I missing anything?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing (at least) [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) plugin so make sure to install:

1. 3 Basic Graphs
2. 5 Additional Graphs
3. KPI vs KPI Graphs

It can be done using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)